# Christoffel Symbol - what does a comma mean in the footer?

Tags: differential-geometry, notation

I am trying to understand the expression for Scalar curvature in terms of the Christoffel symbols.

This is given on Wikipedia by
\begin{equation}
S = g^{ab}(\Gamma^c_{ab,c} - \Gamma^c_{ac,b} + \Gamma^d_{ab}\Gamma^c_{cd} - \Gamma^d_{ac}\Gamma^c_{bd})
\end{equation}
(see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_curvature) for the Wikipedia post)

The thing I'm not sure about is the comma in expression $ab,c$, for example in the footer of the first Symbol. My guess would be that it means
\begin{equation}
\Gamma^c_{ab,c} = \partial_c \Gamma^c_{ab}
\end{equation}

Is that correct ?
The site on Christoffel Symbols on Wikipedia doesn't explain what the comma means so I was wondering whether somebody could help? Many thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In differential geometry, a subscript with a comma often is used to denote the *coordinate* partial derivative relative to some fixed coordinate system.

Along the same lines, a subscript with a semi-colon is often used to denote the *covariant* derivative.

So, given a scalar function $f:M\to\mathbf{R}$,

$$ \nabla_a f = \partial_a f = f_{,a} = f_{;a} $$

For a tensor quantity with coordinate components $f_{abcd}$, the expression
$ f_{abcd,e}$ means the $\partial_e$ of the scalar function $f_{abcd}$. Which is different from $f_{abcd;e}$ which often means the scalar component $(\nabla f)_{eabcd}$.

Comment: See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_derivative#Notation

Comment: that's great help, thanks also for giving this a little context!