# Notation for Christoffel symbols used by Gödel in "An example of a new type of cosmological solution of Einstein field equations of gravitation"

Tags: metric-spaces, notation, physics, mathematical-physics

I have difficult to understand the meaning of the notation used by Gödel in the article cited in the title of this post.

You can find it here: http://www.lygeros.org/10552b.pdf

In the second page (p.448) he use the notation $\Gamma_{0, 12}$ that I don't understand. 
Searching in this website I finally found: [Christoffel Symbol - what does a comma mean in the footer?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104930/christoffel-symbol-what-does-a-comma-mean-in-the-footer)

where is confirmed that the comma means partial derivation. But in that case, the parameter is repeated:

$\Gamma^c_{ab,c}$

In Gödel, it is not.

My question is, is that the same thing?

Do I have to "translate" $\Gamma_{0,12}$ with $\partial_0 \Gamma^0_{12} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_0}\Gamma^0_{12}$?

Thank you very much for helping, it's the last correction I need to do to my thesis! :)

Andrea

---

EDIT: 
The expanded formula is

\begin{align}
\Gamma_{0,12} & = \sum_a  \Gamma_{12}^a g_{a0} \\ & = \frac{1}{2}  \sum_a   \sum_k g_{0a} g^{ak} ( \partial_1 g_{k2}   + \partial_2 g_{1k} -\partial_k g_{12}  )  \\
& = \frac{1}{2}  \sum_k   g_{0}^k ( \partial_1 g_{k2}   + \partial_2 g_{1k} -\partial_k g_{12}  ) 
\\ & = \frac{1}{2}  ( \partial_1 g_{02}   + \partial_2 g_{10} -\partial_0 g_{12}  ) 
\end{align}

Comment: While comma, is often used for partial derivatives, it seems more likely that here it is used to identify which index has been lowered. So my guess would be $\Gamma _{0,12}= \Gamma^a_{\phantom{a}12}\ \  g_{a0}$, which you can easily check by computation.

Comment: Thank you, I've just tried my hypothesis but it does not work. I will check with yours!

Comment: It works! Thank you very much! I added an "edit" to the post in which I report the expanded version, maybe it could help someone else.

Comment: Good to know! +1 for the edit left to possibly help others